# No module named disutils

Tags: python

I'm trying to distribute a python module I wrote. For some reason, I can't located the disutils module. Where might I be able to find it?

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import disutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named disutils
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module is called `distutils`, not `disutils`.